# Nested Array Foreach Issue

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I am very basic new php learner, i having difficulty to get nested array value, here is my json result:

```
stdClass Object
(
[title] => Aao Raja - Gabbar Is Back | Chitrangada Singh
[link] => stdClass Object
    (
        [22] => Array
            (
                [0] => http://r8---sn-aigllnsk.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?mime=video%2Fmp4&id=o-AExJcTxRDvCYsfgA1cIvQDs1v-pvLhKjTPdDh67X19vz&dur=145.542&itag=22&pl=48&ip=2a03:b0c0:1:d0::2f6:c001&sparams=dur,expire,id,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,nh,pl,ratebypass,source,upn&key=cms1&sver=3&expire=1437035009&upn=9lTw9Popb18&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&lmt=1432539432699196&fexp=901816%2C9407809%2C9408142%2C9408420%2C9408710%2C9409172%2C9412774%2C9412846%2C9413149%2C9415664%2C9415958%2C9416126%2C9416370%2C9416656&ipbits=0&signature=3547894526817B37774A7838F8B68493CDD62101.3F143C74D76E8705800445A4CD4476C4F8BCD988&cms_redirect=yes&mm=31&mn=sn-aigllnsk&ms=au&mt=1437013301&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjAzLmxocjE0KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&utmg=ytap1
                [1] => 
                [2] => hd720
            )

        [43] => Array
            (
                [0] => http://r8---sn-aigllnsk.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?mime=video%2Fwebm&id=o-AExJcTxRDvCYsfgA1cIvQDs1v-pvLhKjTPdDh67X19vz&dur=0.000&itag=43&pl=48&ip=2a03:b0c0:1:d0::2f6:c001&sparams=dur,expire,id,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,nh,pl,ratebypass,source,upn&key=cms1&sver=3&expire=1437035009&upn=9lTw9Popb18&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&lmt=1428933984759484&fexp=901816%2C9407809%2C9408142%2C9408420%2C9408710%2C9409172%2C9412774%2C9412846%2C9413149%2C9415664%2C9415958%2C9416126%2C9416370%2C9416656&ipbits=0&signature=266C126464ECDB4CC0FF076CD41F07BCC4DA7E34.08D9F13B7BF7D92FD1E1963336CC7FB8F19FE899&cms_redirect=yes&mm=31&mn=sn-aigllnsk&ms=au&mt=1437013301&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjAzLmxocjE0KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&utmg=ytap1
                [1] => 
                [2] => medium
            )
```

I can access the Title, but can't access the Link urls:

```
echo $title = $json->{'title'};

echo $link = $json->{'link'}->{'22'}->{'0'};
```

How can access the specific link array 22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `echo $title = $json->{'title'};` works because you are accessing an object's property and using `->` is the correct way.
In this case `$json->{'link'}->{'22'}->{'0'}` you are trying to access an array item instead an object's property, because `$json->{'link'}->{'22'}` is an array and not an object. In this case, you should access it in this way: `$json->{'link'}->{'22'}[0]`. In order to avoid this kind of issues and, when you decode your `JSON` to a `PHP object`, you can pass `true` as a second parameter to the function `json_decode` and that will convert the whole `object` into an array. That way, you don't need to worry about accessing elements as object's attributes, you can access them, always, as array items. So, in this case, it would be: `$json["link"]["22"][0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax issue you reveal, its working now :)

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the way you access objects and arrays.

Getting the title is correct via `$json->title`, but the link should be `$json->link->{'22'}[0]` - a mixture of objects and arrays.

FYI the `{'name'}` notation is the same as `name` - only required when you are including variables in your object name e.g. `{$someVar . 'name'}`

Comment: I tried your code, <code>
foreach ($json->link as $links) {
    echo $links[0] . PHP_EOL;
}
</cod>
but i want specific array response LINK > 22 > urls
$json->link[22][0] 

But its not working

Comment: Updated - hadn't noticed the 22 level is an object also

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you use json_decode() function. Do you know that  you can get an array instead of StdClass Object? So, you can use.

```
<?php
$php_array = json_decode($json_string, true);
```