# PHP Looping over Nested Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which looks like this:

```
    Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [dataInfo] => Array
                (
                    [totalRecordCount] => 362
                    [foundCount] => 5
                    [returnedCount] => 5
                )

            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [fieldData] => Array
                                (
                                    [groupAssetID] => 1020
                                    [groupAssetName] => Standard Equipment
                                )

                            [portalData] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [recordId] => 823
                            [modId] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [fieldData] => Array
                                (
                                    [groupAssetID] => 1001
                                    [groupAssetName] => Tools
                                )

                            [portalData] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [recordId] => 829
                            [modId] => 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [fieldData] => Array
                                (
                                    [groupAssetID] => 1005
                                    [groupAssetName] => Spare Parts
                                )

                            [portalData] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [recordId] => 830
                            [modId] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [messages] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 0
                    [message] => OK
                )

        )

)
```

I'm trying to loop over this and extract the values for `groupAssetID` and `groupAssetName` in the `data` array but haven't been able to get this to work so far. I've tried:

```
    foreach ( $records as $record) {
        echo $field . ": " . $value . "<br />\r\n" ;
    }
```

and

```
     foreach ( $records->fieldData as $field=>$value) {
        echo $field . ": " . $value . "<br />\r\n" ;
    }
```

but none of these seem to work and I can't work out the correct syntax here.

Comment: Covered by "[PHP Getting Values From Nested Array](//stackoverflow.com/q/42633112/90527)", "[Can you retrieve nested array by name in php](//stackoverflow.com/q/32983966/90527)", "[Getting nested array data from JSON](//stackoverflow.com/q/48759260/90527)", "[Nested Array Foreach Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31444441/90527)" and likely others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it to run with this syntax:

```
$records = array
(
    'response' => array
        (
            'dataInfo' => array
                (
                    'totalRecordCount' => 362,
                    'foundCount' => 5,
                    'returnedCount' => 5
                ),

            'data' => array
                (
                    0 => array
                        (
                            'fieldData' => array
                                (
                                    'groupAssetID' => 1020,
                                    'groupAssetName' => 'Standard Equipment'
                                ),

                            'portalData' => array
                                (
                                ),

                            'recordId' => 823,
                            'modId' => 1
                        ),

                    1 => array
                        (
                            'fieldData' => array
                                (
                                    'groupAssetID' => 1001,
                                    'groupAssetName' => 'Tools'
                                ),

                            'portalData' => array
                                (
                                ),

                            'recordId' => 829,
                            'modId' => 1
                        ),

                    2 => array
                        (
                            'fieldData' => array
                                (
                                    'groupAssetID' => 1005,
                                    'groupAssetName' => 'Spare Parts'
                                ),

                            'portalData' => array
                                (
                                ),

                            'recordId' => 830,
                            'modId' => 1
                        )
                )
        ),

    'messages' => array
        (
            0 => array
                (
                    'code' => 0,
                    'message' => 'OK'
                )
        )
);

foreach ($records['response']['data'] as $key => $value) {
        
    echo $value['fieldData']['groupAssetID'] . ": " . $value['fieldData']['groupAssetName'] . "<br />\r\n" ;
}
```

Output:

1020: Standard Equipment
1001: Tools
1005: Spare Parts

Is this what you need?